# Trouble Uploading Content on TikTok via Selenium: Need Help Resolving Issues

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automator, tiktok

I am encountering difficulties while attempting to automate the content uploading process on `TikTok` using the Selenium automation tool. Specifically, when I execute the script and click on the 'upload content' button, the content does not get posted as expected. Instead, `TikTok` prompts me if I would like to upload another piece of content.

In contrast, when I manually upload a video on `TikTok`, the platform waits for the video to be completely uploaded before asking if I would like to upload another one. The discrepancy in behavior between manual and automated uploads is the primary issue.

This is my current code{

```
post_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//\*@id="root"\]/div/div/div/div\[2\]/div\[2\]/div\[2\] /div\[8\]/div\[2\]/button')
post_btn.click()

sleep(30)

WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//\[@id="root"\]/div/div/div/div\[2\]/div\[2\]/div\[2\]/div\[9\]/div/div\[1\]/div/div\[1\]')))
```